# Memory Not Release for Array asignment in Mono (C#)

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, mono

In my C# program i have function that in it, i create array of Byte with length of 1000000 and when the function executed , memory show 1MB increase in memory usage.
The problem is here, after returning from function , 1MB memory that allocated in function does not release , WHY????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garbage collector doesn't free up memory right away but

> Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:
>
> > The system has low physical memory. This is detected by either the low memory notification from the OS or low memory indicated by the host.
> >
> > The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.
> >
> > The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

You can find more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals).